# How to don't get the last entry on database handler?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

https://gist.github.com/marataziat/9f5093d75f5a406b6f6889f9ae100883#file-index-html-L56 - My page on loading calls this function, I don't know why. It gets last entry on load. But it must handle only DB updates!

Comment: it would be better if you include all your code directly in your question instead of linking to a gist. In particular, doing so allows for better search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure to fully understand your question, but if you are wondering why you get the database values when you load the page, note that this is the normal behavior.

As explained in the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on), with the `value` event, the «event will trigger **once with the initial data stored at this location**, and then trigger again each time the data changes».

Comment: So which trigger can I use for don't get a value on load?